# Show more values than expected (Extracting encode from header)

Tags: php

I'm trying to show the encode (example:UTF-8) from a header of external website and save it to my JSON File.

It is showing all like this: `text/html; charset=UTF-8` but I don't want show more information than the necessary, I just want show for example: `UTF-8`

**Can someone show me the good way to solve it?**

```
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
$data_array   = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
    $domain   = "http://".$value['domain'];
    $info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"].split("=");
    if (!empty($info)){
        $data_array[$key]['encode'] = $info;
    } else {
        $data_array[$key]['encode'] = "It don't have Encode";
    }
    $json = json_encode($data_array);
    file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
};
```

Comment: what is this supposedly doing? $info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"].split("=");

Comment: @delboy1978uk supposedly it is just showing "UTF-8" and not all data of CONTENT_TYPE text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use `$info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"].split("charset=");` since there may be more than one value with `=`

Comment: @Joanmi debug for it and make sure `get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"]` contains `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: ye it contains it

Comment: @Joanmi `split` will return an array,you need to get the right element,I would suggest you modify your code

Comment: yes, I modified with the delboy answer but It has another problem now

Comment: @Joanmi so it's another problem and this problem can be solve

Comment: yeah it can, the problem is that I don't know how :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"]; // text/html; charset=UTF-8
$ex = explode('=', $info);
$encoding = end($ex);
echo $encoding;
```

Which will output UTF-8

See here https://3v4l.org/NX4Pb

Comment: Ok, it half worked, now, it doesn't take when a page have 2 charset

Comment: lmao, a page with TWO encodings? What do you mean, the string has multiple equals?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some javascript in your php.

Change this:

```
$info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"].split("=");
```

To This:

```
$temp = explode('=', get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"]) ;
// we use end($temp) here in case there is no '=' in your result
$info = $temp[end($temp)] ;
```